# Testing XCode app on device shuts down iPad?

Tags: xcode, ipad, ios-simulator, device

I'm trying to test an app I've been working on, and it works totally fine in the simulator.  But when it builds to the iPad - and it does build fine - it flashes for just a split second on the  app's main screen (which is what it should show), but then the screen immediately turns black, shows the little rotating dots loading icon, then plays the bleep sound that it does when you connect it to the computer.  When I investigate, the iPad is on the screensaver (slide to unlock screen).

The iPad's profile and everything is fine - a new app tests perfectly well on it.  I can't find any glaring inconsistencies. Anyone know what's going on?  I'm really getting frustrated with this.

Comment: Are you jailbroken? What version are you building for? Could you upload your Xcode project folder?

Comment: Not jailbroken, building for version 5.1.

Comment: What about uploading the project, from there I can look at frameworks etc...

Comment: Attach the iPad, use Xcode 'Orgnaizer' then 'Devices' to look at the console log and the app's crash log.

Comment: I find this impossible, apps are **locked** in a sandbox environment. What you explained it is doing in a jailbreaking term it is *respringing*. To respring you **need** root, in sandbox it's not even possible (sudo isn't even installed.) Without further proof I label this *fake* (In my mind.) This may be possible but I fell it is **impossible**.

Comment: Okay, so I tested it using breakpoints near the front end and I somehow managed to get the app to appear on-screen for more than a split second.  I though it was fixed, but as soon as I touched the screen it immediately went black, did the loading thing, played the sound, ect.  I'm not sure how I managed to do that, because it didn't work for subsequent tries.

Comment: GoZoner, the device log is empty.  The console log in the organizer is filled with "unknown kernel", "unknown installd", "unknown DTFetchSymbols", and other such messages.

Comment: Can you run sample apps?  Just to confirm that the Xcode/iPad configuration and connection are working.

Comment: Yes, I started a new project targeted towards 5.1 and it worked flawlessly.

Comment: Could you edit to add your `ViewdidLoad`?

Answer (score 0):

Try recompile all your sources with frameworks for Devices. Not with frameworks for Simulator. Check framework paths: must be locate to iPhoneOS.pltaform, NOT to iPhoneSimulator.platform.

If you using any other libs *.a, then this libs must be a recompiled NOT for simulator, or get libs for device.